# How to access objects in react return()

Tags: reactjs

I have an object coming from a websocket and I have set it to a const newObj.

```
 const newObj = JSON.parse(e.data);
```

I do not want to use JSON.stringify and then pass the object to return() and print it since I cannot access the values of the object. I want to then use the object as props so I can use it in multiple components.

I tried finding a solution to this but nothing seemed to answer my question.

I want to know how an object is handled and passed to the return function so I can output the object this way:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <pre>{ object }</pre>
      <DataTable object = { object } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Error I'm getting is "Object is not a React Child".

Can anyone please help me out with this.

Comment: Why would you want to render the whole object? Why don't you just render the properties you need?

Comment: How do I render only the properties I need? This is the first time I'm working with websockets and objects in react. Can you let me know how I can access only the properties I need.

Comment: look at my answer hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't render an object like `<pre> {object} </pre>`. You have to map through its keys/values/entries:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      {Object.keys(object).map((objKey, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p> {objKey} : {object[objKey]}
          </div>
      ))}
      <DataTable object = { object } />
    </div>
  );
```

This way, you can access the values and the keys of the object, and pass any value to any component.

Comment: I'm using useState Hook the following way:  const [object, setObject] = useState("");  How can I do this setObject(newObj), I cannot do this for an object unless I convert it to string but I need to set my new state to an object value.

Comment: This is an entirely new question. You can set an object to state.

Answer (score 0):

```
const yourComponent = () => {
    const newObj = JSON.parse(e.data);

    const {property1, property2} = newObj

    return (
       <div className="App">
         <Navbar />
         <pre>{property1}</pre>
         <pre>{property2}</pre>
         <DataTable object = {object} />
       </div>
     );
   }
}
```